# Mysql Date SELECT

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to select all dates that haven't pass the current date. So for instance, I want to display every date after 2009-10-06 and NOT dates prior 2009-10-06.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like this, if I understand correctly the question :

```
select *
from your_table
where your_date_field > '2009-10-06'
```

As @James Deville stated, you could use some function to get the current date, instead of hard-coding it in the query.

[`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) will get you date+time ; [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) *(or its aliases [`CURRENT_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date) and `CURRENT_DATE`)* will get you date :

```
mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2009-10-06 19:35:36 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> select curdate();
+------------+
| curdate()  |
+------------+
| 2009-10-06 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

So, in your case, something like this should do :

```
select *
from your_table
where your_date_field > curdate()
```

Comment: I would replace the '2009-10-06' with the function for the current date. I think it's now(), but I don't know for sure.

Comment: +1 Though I'm guessing OP is asking for CURRENT_DATE() function in WHERE clause

Comment: @James: now() returns the current time, nanoseconds included, so date fields later today would show up.

Comment: @James > thanks for your comment ; I've edited my post in consequence -- and shown both now() and curdate()